# Hide a site icon from the search results

Tags: sharepoint-server, search-results, content-search-web-part

I have a content search web part that returns site collections. I don't want the search to show the site icon. [image: The box that shows the site icon]

I can't hide the div because each item has a unique class. Is this possible? I can't find any answer on this anywhere.

Comment: You want to hide only for sitecollection icons? If yes than you can hide the div by finding class ms-srch-item-previewContainer

Comment: Which version of SP you are working with? if 2013+ best way would be to develop a custom display template.

Comment: Which display template are u using?

Comment: I'm using the "Site Item" display template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all that commented and answered! It pushed me in the right direction!

What most were suggesting was to use another display template or to create a custom display template. So that's what I did.

[image: custom display template]

This is a copy from the original display template I was using, "Site Item" (or Item_Site.html) In the copy, that I renamed "Item_Site_noLogo.html", I went in and poked around until this change to the code gave me what I wanted:

```
/*if(!$isNull(ctx.CurrentItem.SiteLogo) && !Srch.U.isDefaultSiteLogo(ctx.CurrentItem.SiteLogo)){ 
                ctx.CurrentItem.csr_PathLength = Srch.U.pathTruncationLengthWithPreview;
                ctx.CurrentItem.csr_PreviewImage = ctx.CurrentItem.SiteLogo;
                ctx.CurrentItem.csr_PreviewImageAltText = Srch.Res.hp_Alt_SiteLogo;
            } else {
                deepLinksClassNoEncode += " ms-srch-item-deepLinks-noPreview";
            }
            */
            deepLinksClassNoEncode += " ms-srch-item-deepLinks-noPreview";
```

I just commented out the section that grabs the site icon and so any result won't show a preview.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can change Item template of content search webpart. Edit the webpart and set item template under display template as **"Two lines"** which will not display any images.

[image]

**OutPut:**

[image]